# Convert ES6 JavaScript to ES5 format

Tags: javascript, json

There is a code snippet found in other questions but how can I convert that to ES5 format.

Trying to get data from JSON array.

```
const match = (query, input) => input.filter((entry) => Object.entries(query).every(([k, v]) => entry[k] === v));
```

Comment: Hi Joe. Please have a look at the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) for StackOverflow. Typically questions like this one will get closed as too broad.

Comment: There are many good online ES6 to ES5 transpilers. You could try the typescript one: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking this step by step, let’s make the formatting a little more ES5-ish to start with:

```
const match = (query, input) => {
  return input.filter((entry) => {
    return Object.entries(query).every(([k, v]) => {
      return entry[k] === v;
    });
  });
};
```

Removing ES6-specific syntax gives us:

```
function match(query, input) {
  return input.filter(function(entry) {
    return Object.entries(query).every(function(kv) {
      return entry[kv.k] === kv.v;
    });
  });
}
```

And finally, we need to remove that call to [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```
function match(query, input) {
  return input.filter(function(entry) {
    return Object.keys(query).every(function(key) {
      return entry[key] === query[key];
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run ES6 through babel to get ES5

https://babeljs.io/

You can setup a build step so you can develop in ES6 and transpile down to ES5 for older browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
var match = function match(query, input) {
  return input.filter(function (entry) {
    return Object.entries(query).every(function (ref) {
      var k = ref[0],
          v = ref[1];
      return entry[k] === v;
    });
  });
};
```